# Finding numbers above the mean

Tags: go

I could use some help finding all the numbers from a struct array that are above a calculated mean!

```
//MeanMedianMode struct
type MeanMedianMode struct {
    numbers []float64
}

func main() {

    // range of numbers
    dataType := MeanMedianMode{
        numbers: []float64{
            84, 25, 88, 56, 10, 19, 11, 80,
            45, 83, 22, 40, 22, 52, 61, 13, 73, 23, //Data to be used
            90, 89, 6,
        },
    }
```

I've figured out how to pass my data easily and find the average as follows...

```
//CalcMean float64
func (mm *MeanMedianMode) CalcMean() float64 {
    total := 0.0

    for _, v := range mm.numbers {
        total += v
    }

    return (total / float64(len(mm.numbers)))
    //return math.Round(total / float64(len(mm.numbers))) //Should it need to be rounded
}
```

My biggest issue is replicating that process and using the values stored in the array within another function and iterating over them to find the values greater than (>) the found mean!
I appreciate the insights!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you'd like to do it, but something like this I guess:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

//MeanMedianMode struct
type MeanMedianMode struct {
    numbers []float64
}

func main() {
    m := &MeanMedianMode{
        numbers: []float64{
            84, 25, 88, 56, 10, 19, 11, 80,
            45, 83, 22, 40, 22, 52, 61, 13, 73, 23,
            90, 89, 6,
        },
    }

    mean := m.CalcMean()
    for _, n := range m.numbers {
        if n > mean {
            fmt.Printf("%.3f is greater than the mean\n", n)
        }
    }

}

//CalcMean float64
func (mm *MeanMedianMode) CalcMean() float64 {
    total := 0.0

    for _, v := range mm.numbers {
        total += v
    }

    return (total / float64(len(mm.numbers)))
}
```

Comment: Perfect! That worked out great. For the sake of following how I did it, I reworked the code into another function and appended it to another array to return back to main. Sometimes I just get so wrapped up on the little things I get absolutely stuck on them, haha. Thanks again